# missing a temporary folder wordpress upload

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress installed . Host provider is 1&1. Now if i tried to upload media file it show me the error **missing a temporary folder** . I also define a path fpr temp directory . I refer this link [link](https://support.fastwebhost.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/322/26/wordpress-is-giving-error-missing-a-temporary-folder--while-uploading-imagemedia) . And created the php.ini file in the home directory . My php.ini file content is

```
upload_max_filesize = 16M
upload_tmp_dir = on
upload_tmp_dir = /epigram.co.uk/tmp
```

I also tried to change wp-config file and added this

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR','/epigram.co.uk/tmp');
```

Also tried with full path . like

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp');
```

Nothing helped me . any help will be appreciated .Thanks

Comment: That error is thrown by PHP and likely you will need to contact your host to have them specify a temporary directory (e.g. upload_tmp_dir in php.ini)

Comment: there is allready a php.ini file on my wordpress root folder. Can't i set this from here??

Comment: just posted a answer with the steps, please check

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `php.ini` file which is located in `etc/` folder, remove comment from the line  `upload_tmp_dir` (by deleting the semi-colon “;”) and pointing the variable to a folder using an absolute path.

1.) open a terminal

2.) create a temporary folder for all apache tasks in your user folder and grant all right to all users:

```
mkdir wwwtmp && chmod 0777 wwwtmp
```

3.) edit php.ini with your text editor and set the temporary folder (you must switch to root user)

```
 su
 vim /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
 upload_tmp_dir = /home/my_user/wwwtmp/
```

**Remeber to remove preceding “;”**

4.) save the file (in vim type :wq an press enter) and restart xampp using this command

```
/opt/lampp/./lampp restart
```

I hope this will remove error if everything went fine.

Comment: i don't have this access . I have 1&1 host

Comment: if you don't have access then you must consult with your hosting providers. otherwise follow the steps then definitely you will get success

Answer (score 2):

**Problem : WordPress is giving error on image upload : "image.jpg" has failed to upload due to an error "Missing a temporary folder."**

If you are receiving this error please follow these simple  instructions below:

1. Create a `"tmp"` folder in your WordPress root directory with `777` permissions. This can be done by your FTP program.
2. Also create a `"php.ini"` file in same location.
3. Add the following in php.ini file:

   **`upload_max_filesize = 16M`**

   **`upload_tmp_dir = on`**

   **`upload_tmp_dir = /home/username/public_html/wordpressDir/tmp`**

Please make sure to replace username with your hosting username, and wordpressDir with the directory name of your WordPress install.
If you have installed WordPress on your homepage then the path will be like: upload_tmp_dir = /home/username/public_html/tmp

4. Copy the same php.ini file to your wp_admin folder.

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

My server is a shared one powerd by plesk. I just changed the PHP vesion from 7.something to 5.something, and the problem was solved! I can upload images to the wordpress media galery

Answer (score 1):

This error can happen if you are using IIS server and a fastCGI module with Thread-safe version of Php. As the Php download page states:

IIS
If you are using PHP as FastCGI with IIS you should use the Non-Thread Safe (NTS) versions of PHP.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for this, worked on IIS after all else failed,

Answer (score -1):

Add From Server plugin saved my time.
it's easy to use, just upload your image through ftp and use Add from sever plugin to import to your Media Library.

Answer (score -1):

On Linux at aws. The below worked for me

```
chmod -R 775 /tmp
```